# Search breaks when querying main loop for category

Tags: query-posts, wp-query, search

In my theme I provide an option for users to set a 'blog category' that queries and displays only posts from that category on `index.php` using `WP_Query`:

```
$shortname = get_option('of_shortname');
$cat_option = get_option($shortname.'_cats_in_blog');
$catid = get_cat_ID($cat_option);
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
   'cat' => $catid,
   'paged' => $paged
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// Queries fine, but search stops working       
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

// Loop stuff here

endwhile;
```

This works well, but the search widget breaks. I have also tried using `query_posts` but that has the opposite effect; the queried category isn't shown but the search still functions. Here's that code:

```
$shortname = get_option('of_shortname');
$cat_option = get_option($shortname.'_cats_in_blog');
$catid = get_cat_ID($cat_option);

// Search is working, querying is not
global $query_string; // required
$posts = query_posts($query_string.'&posts_per_page=3&cat=$catid');

while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

// Loop stuff here

endwhile;
```

I checked the `$catid` variable and it is returning what is should. Am I querying the wrong way or in the wrong place? Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second example, I think you're initiating your Loop incorrectly. You're declaring `$query`, which hasn't been globalized?

```
// Search is working, querying is not
global $query_string; // required
$posts = query_posts($query_string.'&posts_per_page=3&cat=$catid');

while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
```

Try omitting `$query` from your Loop initiation?

```
// Search is working, querying is not
global $query_string; // required
$posts = query_posts($query_string.'&posts_per_page=3&cat=$catid');

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

...and see if that makes a difference?

For the first example, what does "*the search Widget breaks*" mean?

**EDIT**

Wow, I completely overlooked this: you're passing your *variable* as a *string*:

```
$posts = query_posts($query_string.'&posts_per_page=3&cat=$catid');
```

Try this instead:

```
$posts = query_posts( $query_string . '&posts_per_page=3&cat=' . $catid );
```

...so that your `$catid` gets parsed properly.

Comment: By search Widget breaks, I mean stops functioning - it just reloads the page when I search something. Removing $query doesn't make a difference - the loop still shows posts from all categories, but the search does work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Okay, may have found the problem with the second example. See edited answer.

Comment: Came across a problem - the query stops working when I change to a static homepage. Any ideas? Thanks again.